# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file on line 5

Tags: php

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:\Program Files\wamp\www\workspace\DiaryApp\upload\".$new_image_name);
?>
```

Please help me out with the error I am new to php

Answer (score 5):

Escape the last `\` in the path parameter of `move_uploaded_file()`.

```
"C:\Program Files\wamp\www\workspace\DiaryApp\upload\\"
```

Otherwise you're actually escaping the closing string delimiter `"` and adding it to the string as a [literal double-quote](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). This means the string is not terminated before it's concatenated with the following variable, `$new_image_name`, leading to the error you specified.

Comment: Now I get the following error after changing the path parameter Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\workspace\DiaryApp\upload.php on line 4

Comment: if I change the path parameter to //C:\Program Files\wamp\www\workspace\DiaryApp\upload\ I get the unexpected $end error at line 5

Comment: @user2085603 The second error you've mentioned is a separate issue. It means that for some reason `$_FILES['file']` is undefined. This could for various reasons. Try following the tutorial in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php.

Comment: @user2085603 But all in all, you're original question has been resolved. Please consider accepting one of the answers you were given. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the last line to:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:\\Program Files\\wamp\\www\\workspace\\DiaryApp\\upload\\".$new_image_name);
```

So as to escape all the backslashes in the path name

Answer (score 2):

Use forward slash / in file paths.  This will work on windows.   Also, write these paths to a variable.  You really don't want these hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are new (not that it's a problem, everyboddy must lurn ;) )

a `\` is a notice for php that ther will folow a special char
e.g. \n \r \" \'

so thats why you have to "**escape**" your `\`.

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:\\Program Files\\wamp\\www\\workspace\\DiaryApp\\upload\\".$new_image_name);
?>
```

this is only when you plase your string between **"** (double quotes).
You may also place them between **'** (single quotes), then you must not escape them.
**==> not true, you must always escape `\`**

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'C:\\Program Files\\wamp\\www\\workspace\\DiaryApp\\upload\\'.$new_image_name);
?>
```

**this can be usefull for education:**

So I here you thinking: "whats the difference between **"** & **'** ?".

Well whit **" "** you can place vars between your quotes e.g.

```
<?php
$str="string";
echo "this is a $str.";
?>
```

the output will be: **this is a string.**

with **' '**, all the characters are taken literally

```
<?php
$str="string";
echo 'this is a $str.';
?>
```

the output will be: **this is a $str.**

Comment: \ still needs to be escaped in single quotes, look at the syntax highlighting for what I mean.

Comment: hmmm, y're right Alex. thanx for telling me. so my post is not at the right place here... the only good thing is that user2085603 know something more about " & '... I edited my post